# When to use a Backbone.View vs. Backbone.Marionette.ItemView?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I'm working my way through my first attempt at using Backbone.Marionette and wondered if there is any reason to use a Backbone.Marionette.ItemView when a simple Backbone.View will suffice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Marionette's ItemView provides a default `render` and `close` method which do a few things for you.

`render` does the following (amongst other things):

1) Marks view as !this.isClosed (related to showing views in Regions, another Marionette concept)

2) Triggers before and after render events

3) Calls a `serializeData` method to get data (defaults to data from either `this.model` or `this.collection`.

4) Gets the template (possibly from TemplateCache) and renders via Marionetter.Renderer

5) Binds UI elements

In addition to this "free" `render` method, you also get close functionality.

Of course, if you are using a CollectionView/ItemView combination (which is very powerful) or a CompositeView/ItemView, you HAVE to use an ItemView.

Outside of those cases, one big  benefit is that you KNOW your view is going to be compatible with Marionette Regions.  Ideally, in a Marionette app, you use separate regions to show your views, like so:

```
var myView = new MyView();

// render and display the view
MyApp.mainRegion.show(myView);

// closes the current view
MyApp.mainRegion.close();
```

If `MyView` is a Marionette ItemView, this will work like a charm.  If it is just a raw Backbone View, you will probably need to do some work to make sure that it works as planned.

In my apps, I typically just opt for using ItemView as the basis for all of my non-Collection and non-Composite Views.

Comment: Glad to be of help. :) I have found the Marionette source to be pretty easy to read/understand, so you might try giving them a look if you're ever confused on how/why things work like they do.